# How to send utf-8 encoded string with volley post paramters

Tags: android, utf-8, android-volley

I am sending a post request using volley library in android. I am sending the post parameters using below method

> @Override
>                   protected Map getParams() {
>                       return postParams;
>                   }

In this post params I want to send a string with utf-8 encoding. I am using the below logic to convert it in utf-8 but it is not working.

```
byte[] bytes = mCommentBox.getText().toString().trim().getBytes("UTF-8");
String commentBody = new String(bytes, Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
```

I am adding this commentBody variable in post parameters but this encoding is not working.

How can I get this working, please help me.

Thanks a lot in advanced.